# Free Virtual Machine for mac OS X 10.5.8 (Leopard)

Tags: virtual-machine

Are there any free VM's out there for Mac OS X 10.5.8 (Leopard)? I've looked at virtual box, but it only works for 10.6 (Snow Leopard) and onwards. I really don't want to pay to upgrade my OS either. Also looked at VMWare, which isn't free.

Update: currently working myw ay thru Virtual Box version 3.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are older versions available for Leopard: [link](http://mac.oldapps.com/virtualbox.php?system=mac_os_x_10.5_leopard_intel). Can't test and verify though, have no Mac at that version available.

Comment: Have you successfully installed virtual box on your computer? I'm stuck at the setup stage, getting a "no bootable medium found" error. Assuming I have to download Ubuntu, looks like I need to burn it on a CD. Do you have any insight?

Comment: I have VBox on Lion, you can't start a VM without bootable media (although you can install and run the VBox Manager). Download an .ISO file and configure the CD-ROM drive in the machine settings to use that ISO file as the drive's contents. Also, these kinds of things belong on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com), this page is for programming-related topics.